# Prove that $n^m+x$ is not prime generally if $n+x$ is (in $\Bbb N$)

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

If $n + x$ with $n, x \in \Bbb N$ is prime, is it possible to prove generally, that $n^m + x$ with $n, x, m \in \Bbb N$ is not prime for at least one $m$? If yes, how can this be done?

EDIT: There was one comment stating that this is not possible, if you take $n = 1$ and for example $x = 2$. That is right. I am interested in solutions for $n > 1$.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right of corse. I edited the question.

Comment: I edited my question again. It was right what you understood first. I think I already got the solution based on your answer, I will comment it immediately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let
$$  P = n+x  $$ be prime, as stated. What can you say about 
$$ n^{P} + x \pmod P?  $$
What can you say about 
$$ n^{2P-1} + x \pmod P?  $$
$$ n^{3P-2} + x \pmod P?  $$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Example: $n=2,x=3,P=5.$
$$ 2 + 3 = 5 \equiv 0 \pmod 5 $$
$$ 2^5 + 3 = 32+3 = 35 \equiv 0 \pmod 5 $$
$$ 2^9 + 3 = 512+3 = 515 \equiv 0 \pmod 5 $$
$$ 2^{13} + 3 = 8192+3 = 8195 \equiv 0 \pmod 5 $$

Comment: Thank you, I understood the first part. $n^P \equiv n \pmod P$ implies $n^P + x \equiv n + x \pmod P$. As $P=n+x$, $n+x \mod P=0$. That means that $P$ divides every number $n^m+x$ if $m=P$, so that is the proof I was looking for.

Comment: I will think about the other two terms you posted tomorrow, as it's already quite late here. Thank you for your fast help!

Comment: I think you can remove the note about the edit, you understood perfectly right what I meant ;-). Thanks again!